# Serialize work group items in kernel

Tags: opencl

I have a kernel that performs two tasks, A followed by B.

A is parallelized over all work items, and B is very sequential, so only
the first work item performs it.

Each work item could perform a part of B if I could make them execute in sequence.
This is a 2D kernel, and I would like to make the work items execute in a raster pattern.

Is this possible?  One idea would be a local variable that all work items can read, and the unique
work item that matches the variable would execute and modify the variable so it would trigger the next work item to execute.

Any ideas/patterns on how to do this?

Thanks!

Edit:

Here is some pseudo code for how my kernel currently works:

```
void myKernel(void) {

    // perform A task (all work items are active)

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEMORY_FENCE);

   if (get_local_id(0) == 0 && get_local_id(1) == 0) {
      //perform task B
  }

}
```

and here is how I would like it to work:

```
// 10 x 10 2D kernel
void myKernel(void) {

    // perform A task (all work items are active)

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEMORY_FENCE);

    local activeIndex =0;
    while (activeIndex < 100) {
        if ( get_local_id(0) + 10* get_local_id(1) == activeIndex) {
             // perform part of task B
             activeIndex++;
        } 
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEMORY_FENCE);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit 2:  I tried this code on my HD 7700, but it was very slow. I guess I will stick to local memory instead.

Comment: Do you have some example code to show us? Your question is fairly vague. What's B exactly? A lot of algorithms can be efficiently parallelized, even if it's not always obvious.

Comment: Thanks, Cicada. Task B is an arithmetic coder, where the coder state at a given pixel depends on the previous pixel, etc. So, it really can't be parallelized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you are describing on a per-workgroup basis. Barriers will give you exactly the functionality you need. If you want to do this on a global level, you are out of luck. Using a variable to check the global state before resuming the kernel is known as a 'spin-lock', and I have caused a few WSOD (white screen of death) situations trying this out for myself.

There is nothing wrong with the example code you posted, except maybe the lack of params...

```
void myKernel(void) {

    // perform A task (all work items are active)

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEMORY_FENCE);

   if (get_local_id(0) == 0 && get_local_id(1) == 0) {
      //perform task B
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, mfa.  I just need to synchronize the work items in a work group.  I guess I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You have no guarantee that all the "A" work items will run together; they can run in batches. So you can't do "B", even for just one work item, in the same kernel as "A". If all "A" work items must finish before "B" starts, "B" must be a separate kernel, which you can run with whatever global work size makes the most sense for your problem.